# Looping encounters on Heroku Dyno Upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, dyno

I've encountered some problems when I tried to upgrade or add a dyno on my application. After using 2 dynes, it seems like my application process started looping and the process in not proceeding. It's working fine when I'm using 1 dyno server. Do I still have to configure anything? Because based on the tutorials that I've watched, I only have to drag to add server and Heroku will do the other process. Please help me. Thank you so much!